# Warning the user onback

Tags: javascript, back-button

I have been trying to use backfix.min.js from here

https://code.google.com/p/group972301/source/browse/ep+web+for+checkout/WebContent/js/backfix.min.js?r=61

to implement a warning on back button warning to keep users on a page unless they wish to leave.

I have been using the following code:

```
bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function () {
                backClicked = true;
                alert("Back Button PRessed.");
            };
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                if (backClicked) {
                    backClicked = false;
                    return "Your place will not be saved.\nFurther warnings will not be shown.";
                }
            };
```

The issue is that it works once, but any subsequent back clicks just allow a back as the onback function is not firing.

is there any other good way of doing this?

Comment: You want to show the warning only in back button? Or every time user tries to refresh/leave the page?

Comment: really just the back button.